# "Cannot read configuration file" Error when accessing the image from the virtual directory on IIS whose physical path is network folder

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have deployed my application on IIS 7.0. I wanted a shared Image folder in my application, so I created a virtual directory inside my deployed application on IIS.

I set the physical path for this virtual directory to a shared folder on another machine. Now when I try to browse any image from this shared folder I get the following error:

> **HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error**
>
> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
>
> **Detailed Error Information:**
>   **Module** IIS Web Core
>   **Notification** BeginRequest
>   **Handler** Not yet determined
>   **Error Code** 0x8007052e
>   **Config Error** Cannot read configuration file
>   **Config File** \?\UNC\WINSERVER1\hpu_images_staging\web.config
>   **Requested URL** http://[IPAddress]/Images/Temp_Harsh/photos/086b88b9-a228-4e0d-ba29-436c74ff5258.jpg
>   **Physical Path** \WINSERVER1\hpu_images_staging\vetphotos\086b88b9-a228-4e0d-ba29-436c74ff5258.jpg
>   **Logon Method** Not yet determined
>   **Logon User** Not yet determined
>   **Failed Request Tracing Log Directory** C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically adding the right username and password for the VD in Basic settings resolved this..

Comment: I had the same issue, though it was from a DMZ web server to an intranet file server. The file server had the correct network account setup on it, and manually browsing to the folder worked (even Content View in IIS worked), but accessing the virtual directory via a browser failed until I created a local user with the same password on the intranet server and gave it the necessary permissions - then this error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Does this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942055 help? I see that Cause#2 matches what you are doing. See if that helps

Comment: I tried these resolutios but did not help.. Please let me know if there are any other resolutions to this problem.